# Simple jQuery slideDown doesn't work for two

Tags: jquery, menu, fade

Problem:

I have 2 slide downs, kind of a menu.

```
<div id="one" style="background-color: red; width: 200px; heihgt: 125x; margin-left: 5px; float: left;">One</div>
<div id="two" style="background-color: red; width: 200px; heihgt: 125x; margin-left: 5px; float: left;">Two</div><br />
<div id="block1" style="background-color: blue; width: 200px; height: 300px; margin-left: 5px; float: left; display: none;">Blabla</div>
<div id="block2" style="background-color: blue; width: 200px; height: 300px; margin-left: 5px; float: left; display: none;">Blabla2</div>
```

And this jQuery script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one").hover(function() {
        $("#block1").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $("#two").hover(function() {
        $("#block2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

The main idea is to slide down #block1, if you hover #one, and slide down #block2 if you hover #two

But there is the problem:

When hovering #one, It works fine.

But when you hover #two, nothing happens.

If you hover #one and then #two, it will work, but at the end it will slideDown #block1 again.
I have no idea what causing it?

**Question**

What have I done wrong? How do I make it so when you hover #one, it toggles #block1, and when I hover #two, it toggles #block2.

I just started learnign jQuery, and really confused of the syntax.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover take two handlers: when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements. It should work if you use `mouseover` or add another handler for your `hover` method

---

Your HTML and CSS got problem so I will take this HTML as an example:

```
<div id="one" class="div" style="background-color: red; width: 200px; heihgt: 125x; margin-left: 5px; float: left;">One</div>
<div id="two" class="div" style="background-color: red; width: 200px; heihgt: 125x; margin-left: 5px; float: right;">Two</div><br />
<div id="block1" style="background-color: blue; width: 200px; height: 300px; margin-left: 5px; float: left; display: none;">Blabla</div>
<div id="block2" style="background-color: blue; width: 200px; height: 300px; margin-left: 5px; float: right; display: none;">Blabla2</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".div").each(function(i) {
    var index = i + 1;
    $(this).hover(
      function () {
        $(this).siblings("#block" + index).slideDown("slow");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).siblings("#block" + index).slideUp("slow");
      }
    );
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/azyvS/)**</kbd>

Comment: Since index of `each()` start with 0, but your id is `block1`, `block2` not start with `block0` so I need to increase it 1 by default

Answer (score 1):

Another idea.  There was a spelling issue on "height" and you could try the blocks contained within the divs.

I changed a few things and it works here  http://jsfiddle.net/G3BuZ/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#one").hover(function() {
        $("#block1").slideDown("slow");
    });
        $('#one').mouseleave(function() {
        $("#block1").slideUp("slow");
    });
        $("#two").hover(function() {
        $("#block2").slideDown("slow");
    });
        $('#two').mouseleave(function() {
        $("#block2").slideUp("slow");
    });  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HKNDY/3/

This works - hover has two parts (hover `on` and hover `off`). You need to make the block slide back up when the mouse hovers off the `div`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one").hover(function() {
        $("#block1").slideToggle("slow");
    }, function(){
        $("#block1").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $("#two").hover(function() {
        $("#block2").slideToggle("slow");
    }, function(){
         $("#block2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is working. If you move over the right box, you will have `Blabla2` in there. The problem is that the left div with `Blabla` is hidden, so `Blabla2` floats to the very left, not under `#two`. You will need to change your CSS for that.

Comment: Oh.. I get this now... Thanks a lot!